# Show translation missing in rails 3 like the rails 2 way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Since I'm using rails 3 there are a lot of translation missing records in production environment because of the way translation missing strings are handled in rails 3, for example the output of translation missing is now :

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: fr.admin.orders_logs.update.title">Title</span>
```

In our application we see "Title" so we think the translation is ok but infact the translation is missing, if I"m not wrong the displayed text was "translation missing: fr.admin.orders_logs.update.title" in Rails 2.X

How I can activate this again that he shows me the error message instead of putting it just as title in a span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a feature in Rails. See: https://gist.github.com/rails/rails/issues/6489

A possible fix is to override the culprit by placing something like this to application.rb:

```
module ActiveModel
  module Translation
    def human_attribute_name(attribute, options = {})
      defaults  = []
      parts     = attribute.to_s.split(".", 2)
      attribute = parts.pop
      namespace = parts.pop

      if namespace
        lookup_ancestors.each do |klass|
          defaults << :"#{self.i18n_scope}.attributes.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key}/#{namespace}.#{attribute}"
        end
        defaults << :"#{self.i18n_scope}.attributes.#{namespace}.#{attribute}"
      else
        lookup_ancestors.each do |klass|
          defaults << :"#{self.i18n_scope}.attributes.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key}.#{attribute}"
        end
      end

      defaults << :"attributes.#{attribute}"
      defaults << options.delete(:default) if options[:default]
      defaults << "MISSING TRANSLATION"+defaults.to_yaml # defaults << attribute.humanize

      options.reverse_merge! :count => 1, :default => defaults
      I18n.translate(defaults.shift, options)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the i18n.fallbacks config to false?

```
# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
# the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
config.i18n.fallbacks = false
```

Comment: yes, I placed the line in my development.rb environment file, but it does not change anything.